# MongoDB Math functions like $mod accept NumberLong in mongo shell but not through Java driver

Tags: math

This is a sample record in my collection "compliance":

```
{
    "_id" : "fc750415-9425-413c-906d-0c15e1628b0d",
    "gcid" : "e9c5c788-a8df-4080-a94f-7949fc17bfa0",
    "audittime" : NumberLong("1437316807198"),
    "auditmonth" : NumberLong("1427826600000"),
    "checksum" : "30e4ae5aa93cfb17ad9876df6feea17149a0f347",
    "policyids" : [
        "be0edaa7-6972-4397-8c0b-e8cceec5b929"
    ],
    "rectype" : "processed",
    "starttime" : NumberLong("1437316807198"),
    "transid" : "-1",
    "transtime" : NumberLong("1437316807198")
}
```

Here is my MongoDB query which will be give me the count of records with "audittime" field boundaries of 100 milliseconds:

```
db.compliance.aggregate([
             {$project: 
                   {
                    id: 1,
                    rectype: 1,
                    audittime: 1, 
                    auditday: { $subtract: ["$audittime", { $mod: ["$audittime", 100]}]}
                   }
             }
             {$match: 
                {
                 rectype:"assigned", 
                 audittime:{$lte:NumberLong("1437141242748"), $gte:NumberLong("1437139368604")}
                }
             },
             {$group:
                {
                 _id: "$auditday",
                 count : {$sum:1}
                }
             }
            ]       
        )
```

This works perfectly in the mongo shell, but when I construct the same query using the Java driver (version 2.10), it gives me the following error:

```
command failed [aggregate]: { "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27018" , "errmsg" : "exception: $mod only supports numeric types, not NumberLong64 and String" , "code" : 16611 , "ok" : 0.0 , "$gleStats" : { "lastOpTime" : { "$ts" : 1437488274 , "$inc" : 1} , "electionId" : { "$oid" : "55acc0fada2f10f0d6c7e6c1"}}}
```

Why does the Java driver refuse to take long values for arithmetic functions while mongo shell accepts? Is there a way to convert NumberLong values to numeric types without updating the record?
Is there an alternative way of writing this query using Java driver?